# Parse a JDBC ResultSet into a CSV in-memory String

Tags: java, csv, jdbc

I am executing a query which is returning a ResultSet object. I want to convert this ResultSet into a CSV String in memory.

The reason I want to do this is that once I have the CSV String, I want to invoke a REST API endpoint and pass it this CSV data.

Are there any existing libraries or utilities I can use to convert from a ResultSet into an **in memory** String? I.e. not into a file..

Comment: Right now, this reads like "please write this code for me." That's not what SO is for. Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Off-topic, but [Apache Commons DbUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbutils/examples.html) can help you do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
    StringWriter output = new StringWriter();
    CsvWriterSettings settings = new CsvWriterSettings(); // many options here, check the documentation

    ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
    int columns = md.getColumnCount();

    String[] headers = new String[columns];
    for(int i = 1; i <= columns; i++){
        headers[i - 1] = md.getColumnLabel(i);
    }

    //if an input value is null, you may want print "NULL"
    settings.setNullValue("NULL");

    // if an input value is not null, but is empty (e.g. ""), the writer can be configured to print "NULL" as well
    settings.setEmptyValue("NULL");

    // Sets the file headers (used for finer selection of fields, these values won't be written automatically)
    settings.setHeaders(headers);

    // Creates a writer with the above settings;
    CsvWriter writer = new CsvWriter(output, settings);

    // Writes the headers specified in the settings
    writer.writeHeaders();

    Object[] row = new Object[columns];
    while(rs.next()){
        for(int i = 1; i <= columns; i++){
            row[i - 1] = rs.getObject(i);
        }
        writer.writeRow(row);
    }

    writer.close();

    String yourString = output.toString();
```